# How can I find about different types of Layers to use in pycaffe?

Tags: pycaffe

Where should I look for documentation or hints for different kinds of layers available in pycaffe? and their attributes?
I want to define an architecture which uses batch-normalization, but I'm lost, in the examples there is only convolution, fully connected, max-pooling and relu layers. nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycaffe is just a wrapper/interface for caffe. 
Check [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/include/caffe/layers) for the list of layers available in caffe.
Find the layer you are interested in (e.g. batch_norm_layer.hpp). Open the header file and check the method `type()`. The return value of this method (e.g. `"BatchNorm"`) is what you are looking for and is used in pycaffe.

Read the comments at the top of each header file. It explains layer details and their input parameters.
As a supplementary approach, take a look at [layer implementations](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/src/caffe/layers). Check the `LayerSetUp` method and look for `param` or `this->layer_param_`. You can find the exact parameters and their names.
The parameters' names are the same as those in the network description (.prototxt) files. Find an example and you will figure out the parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much